# nodeJS get Error in simple code

Tags: javascript, node.js

i'm newbie in nodeJS, after successfully installing socket.io by npm command i'm create simple js as this code:

```
var app   = require('http').createServer(handler),
    io    = require('socket.io').listen(app),
    fs    = require('fs');

function handler( request, response ) {

  fs.readFileSync( __dirname + '/index.html', function( error, data ) {

    if( error ) throw error;
    response.writeHead(200);
    response.end( data );

  });
};

app.listen( 1377 )
io.sockets.on( 'connection', function( socket ) {
  socket.on( 'loginRequest', function( data ) {
    login( data );
  });
});

function login( data, socket) {
  return socket.emit('loginAnswer', true)
};
```

this file can be run correctly by `node application.js` without any problem, now i'm create simple html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.4.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io('http://localhost');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <form onsubmit='requestLogin()'>
        <input id='username' type='text'>
        <input id='password' type='password'>
        <input type='submit'>
      </form>
        </body>
  </html>
```

name of this file is index.html, i'm using xampp and both of files are in htdocs root, htdocs is only have this files, now i'm open `localhost:1337` in browser and i get error

after change address to `localhost:1337` i get this error:

```
Unable to connect
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost:1337.
```

Comment: Try accessing `localhost:1337/`

Comment: Your port is `app.listen( 1377 )`, but you connect to it using `localhost:80`

Comment: @royhowie i get this error: Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost:1337.

Answer (score -1):

You use `fs.readFileSync` where you should use `fs.readFile`,
also realizing that you listen to port 1377, and try to use port 1337,
in index.html add the port to the socket connection `io('http://localhost:1377');`